# OnClick event with react and type script

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-chartjs-2

How do I handle onclick with react and typescript?
Moreover, is there a possible to show another chart onclick (I mean like to expand the clickable item info)?

That's the code I'm using:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  BarElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
} from 'chart.js';
import { Bar ,getElementAtEvent ,getDatasetAtEvent } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import { faker } from '@faker-js/faker';


ChartJS.register(
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  BarElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend
);

export const options = {
  plugins: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Chart.js Bar Chart - Stacked',
    },
  },
  responsive: true,
  scales: {
    x: {
      stacked: true,
    },
    y: {
      stacked: true,
    },
  },
};

const labels = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'];

export const data = {
  labels,
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Dataset 1',
      data: labels.map(() => faker.datatype.number({ min: -1000, max: 1000 })),
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
    },
    {
      label: 'Dataset 2',
      data: labels.map(() => faker.datatype.number({ min: -1000, max: 1000 })),
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
    },
    {
      label: 'Dataset 3',
      data: labels.map(() => faker.datatype.number({ min: -1000, max: 1000 })),
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(53, 162, 235)',
    },
  ],
};

export function BarChart() {
  return <div style={{width:1500}}>
    <Bar options={options}  width={80}  
  height={30} data={data} />
  </div> 
}
```

Comment: Please show some code example that you tried and images. The question is incomplete.

Comment: What component wil listen on the click event? Please provide further information.

Comment: when click on one of the bars